# ¿Cuál es el origen del sentido de "chiflado" como bebedor de licor?

Tags: etimología, significado

Buscando el origen del término *chiflado* como sinónimo de *loco*, encontré la segunda acepción del verbo [***chiflar***](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8kGKRv6):

> 2. tr. coloq. Beber mucho y con presteza vino o licores.

Si bien me parece como una 'razón válida' para esbozar una respuesta a mi inquietud original (*chiflado* como símil de loco suponiendo que un bebedor suele perder la razón), me genera la pregunta: ¿Cuál es el origen del sentido de *chiflado* como bebedor de licor?

Veo además que esta acepción viene al menos desde el diccionario de 1780, a diferencia de la definición de [*chiflado*](https://dle.rae.es/?id=8kFRV4b) (*que ha perdido la razón*) que aparece a finales del siglo pasado, lo que refuerza mi teoría que el chiflado bebedor pudo transformarse en el chiflado loco.

Comment: De primeras, pensaría que es un origen similar al que tiene el uso del verbo *soplar* también con este sentido. Pero el hecho de que la acepción con el significado de *silbar* aparezca después de esta en el diccionario me hace dudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo *chiflar* aparece en diccionarios desde 1570, traducido a otros idiomas como el francés (*sifler*, *chifler*) o el italiano (*fischiare*, *sischiare*, *suffolare*). Covarrubias en 1611 lo define así:

> CHIFLAR, es hazer con la boca un cierto sonido, a modo de silvo; y muchas vezes en señal de hazer burla, y escarnio de alguno, del qual dezimos que le chiflan los muchachos.

Así que básicamente *chiflar* y *silbar* eran sinónimos. En 1617 un diccionario lo traduce al inglés como *to whistle*, así que parece que no hay duda. Sin embargo, en 1620 un diccionario ya lo traduce al italiano así: *bere bene* ("beber bien"), y *chiflador* lo traduce como *gran bevitore* ("gran bebedor").

En 1729 el *Autoridades* ya lo recoge, además de como "silvar" (así está registrado) y como "mofar, hacer burla y escarnio", como "dar por perdida y sin remedio una cosa" y como:

> CHIFLAR. Por alusion se dice y toma mui comunmente por beber, y con particularidad vino, con prestéza y en cantidad.

No lo pone expresamente, pero yo diría que la acepción de "beber" debe provenir por la forma en que se ponen los labios, similar tanto al silbar como al acercar los labios la copa de vino.

Por tanto, efectivamente parece que el sentido de *chiflado* como "bebido" es mucho más antiguo que el de "loco", el cual surgió mucho después.

> *... y, metiendo la pipa entre los cristales de aquel néctar suavísimo, empecé a chiflar de tal suerte que no sentí la frialdad del mar ni el rocío de la mañana.*
>
> Anónimo, "La vida y hechos de Estebanillo González", 1646 (España).

Curiosamente, no encuentro usos del participio *chiflado* como "bebido". Encuentro un caso en el siglo XVIII con el sentido de "hurtado" ("perdido sin remedio", como decía el *Autoridades*), y luego ya otros a finales del XIX ya con el sentido de "loco". En todo caso, el *Autoridades* y demás registran *chiflado* como el participio de *chiflar* simplemente.

Comment: todavía son sinónimos silbar y chiflar